# SoP. If i wear armor without the Somatic Casting Drawback do I still impose arcane spell failure?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spellcasting, spell-components, spheres-of-power

Using Spheres of Power, instead of traditional casting. If I'm using a class that isn't proficient in armor, but don't take the Somatic Casting Drawback, do I still take the risk of arcane spell failure from using my magic talents?

I built a custom sphere witch but I'm not using the traditional Witch Casting Tradition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

The Spheres System has its own [Casting Traditions](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/casting-traditions), which determine drawbacks like [Somatic Casting](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/casting-traditions#toc36). The Arcane Spell Failure [ASF] rule has been completely replaced by the casting traditions rules within Spheres. So long as you only employ Sphere effects (like magical talents), and you do not have the Somatic Casting drawback once or twice, you need not worry about ASF at all.

Note that the [standard Witch casting tradition](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/casting-traditions#toc303) does have that drawback twice, but you are free to choose another casting tradition and are not required to take this tradition.

However, keep in mind that all of this only applies when using material from Spheres. If your Witch (or her familiar) is somehow using normal Pathfinder spellcasting, then this spellcasting would still be subject to Pathfinder's ASF rules. This should only ever occur in the most obscure of circumstances, for example when a [Nethys](https://www.aonprd.com/DeityDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Nethys)-worshipping Wizard grants you the ability to cast an arcane spell via [Imbue with Spell Ability](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Imbue%20with%20Spell%20Ability).